# Can I just replicate an RF amplifier on the same board?

Tags: pcb, amplifier, rf, layout

Currently I have a simple amplifier implemented in a board:

[image]

Right next to its input I wire bond my DUT (few millimeters away). I work with fast pulses, frequency range approx 100 MHz → 1 GHz. This works fine.

Now I have some DUTs that have two channels which I need to monitor simultaneously. So I would like to just make a new board with two replicas of this amplifier, one next to the other, something like this:

[image]

As I am not very experienced with RF I wonder if might there be any hidden RF issue with this, for example that they cannot just share the power supply, they need each an independent RF shielding, etc. Any special precautions for the layout?

An answer with some link or picture showing how this is done by experts would be ideal.

Comment: Every RF circuit is different in it's own way. We have little idea of what components you are using so recommendations are difficult. Nevertheless, you need to ensure that the two sections are separated by a fence of GND with vias between the layers. Ideally each section would be surrounded by a fence of GND. The power input filtering should stop RF getting back into your DC supply, so you can share the same DC supply.

Comment: If the inductors are wire wound, they should be perpendicular to each other (between the two amps).  This prevents magnetic coupling, or interference between them.